# How to use lombok in Eclipse/STS or Intellij Idea?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, spring-tool-suite, lombok

After lombok dependency add into pom.xml and update repository, it can't work well, IDE could not identify lombok's annotaiton. How could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step, you need to add lombok dependency in your pom.xml, and update maven dependencies to download lombok.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And then, if you use Eclipse/STS as your IDE, you need to install lombok. Close your IDE first, and execute below command:

```
C:\Users\a243903\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.16.20>java -jar lombo
k-1.16.20.jar
```

If you use Intellij Idea as your IDE, you need to install lombok plugin:

1. Go to File > Settings > Plugins.
2. Click on Browse repositories...
3. Search for Lombok Plugin.
4. Click on Install plugin. Settings -> Compiler -> Annotation
   Processors, make sure check box Enable annotation processing
5. Restart IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok plugin for IntelliJ is available here:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin

Install it and restart IntelliJ.